# How to loop through an array in SQL where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a MySQL table which has the following columns and records:

```
| Name | Total    | GivenBy      | 
| ---- | -------- | ------------ |
| Z    | 200      |['A','B','C'] |
| X    | 240      |['A','D','C'] |
```

I would like to extract Record No. 1 on the basis of 3rd column where the SQL query would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE GivenBy='B';
```

Is there a way I can loop through the list in third column and take out the respective string as required in the SQL WHERE clause in a single query?

Please note that I cannot add more columns in the table.

If you can please provide the query as MySQL compatible, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The "array" you show isn't quite valid JSON, but if you use double-quotes instead of single-quotes, you can use JSON_TABLE() to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Name CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Total INT NOT NULL,
    GivenBy JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
('Z', 200, '["A","B","C"]'),
('X', 240, '["A","D","C"]');

SELECT Name, Total, g.Value
FROM MyTable
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(GivenBy, '$[*]' COLUMNS(Value CHAR(1) PATH '$')) AS g;

+------+-------+-------+
| name | total | value |
+------+-------+-------+
| X    |   240 | A     |
| X    |   240 | D     |
| X    |   240 | C     |
| Z    |   200 | A     |
| Z    |   200 | B     |
| Z    |   200 | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
```

But the best choice is not to store "arrays" in MySQL. Store the values one per row in a second table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "like" keyword with regex to match your requirements in the third column.

select * from table where givenBy like "%B%";

Something similar would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a script:

1. Retrieve the list of unique values in the `GivenBy` column using the following query:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(GivenBy, '$[*]') AS GivenByValues
     FROM mytable;
   ```
2. Loop through the list of unique values, and for each value, run a query that uses that value in the `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM mytable
    WHERE JSON_SEARCH(GivenBy, 'one', [current_value_from_loop]) IS NOT NULL;
   ```